# Onclick/onchange cancelling eachother

Tags: javascript, forms, function, onclick, onchange

so I have a form, one of its fields call a JavaScript function to make some changes on some other fields content.

Like so:

```
<form>
   <select onchange="montarconselho(distrito,'concelho');" id="distrito">

    other selects here...

   <input onclick="return submitform()" type="submit"id="inserir"/>
<form
```

Now the problem that I am having is that if I leave that onclick function call, the onchange function on the select stops working.

If I erase the onclick call from the button, the onchange on the select starts working!

The functions on each of them have nothing to do with one another so I have no clue what's going on.

Kudos to whoever replies!

Comment: Select elements are not typically self closing. You should have some options in there. Also, that last tag is actually `</form>`, right?

Comment: why not add onsubmit handler to form ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a slight variation of the same problem. 
My onchange is on a text input. I change the input value but leave the focus in that input. I then use the mouse to click a button (or hit an accesskey) which should trigger an onclick.

In my case the onchange runs, but the onclick never fires or is stopped before the handler is called.

The onchange starts a brief ajax process.

If I tab out of the input before clicking the button both events work properly.
It's as though the browser unregisters the onclick event listener until the onchange has finished.

......

Aha! Writing this led me to spot the cunning trap. My onchange handler started by disabling all form inputs while it ran. Duh.

The chances of this being the answer to your problem seem slim, but it shows how hard you sometimes have to look at your code to find an error. You could try tidying up your code a bit: ';' after submitform(), space before id=, two opening form tags in succession?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your code is written like this:

HTML:

```
<form action="/echo/json/">
  <select onchange="montarconselho(distrito,'concelho');" id="distrito">
   <option value"0">0</option>
   <option value"1">1</option>
   <option value"2">2</option>
  </select>    



 <input onclick="return submitform()" type="submit" id="inserir"/>
</form>​
```

JS:

```
var montarconselho​ = function (a,b) {
    alert ('select change');
}
```

if this not work try to post a snippet of your "real" code